# Kotlin DataStore<Preferences> Implementación

Tags: android, kotlin, google-datastore

Estoy intentando implementar DataStore Preferences en Kotlin, en un ViewModel. Tengo el Repostor, les dejo el código

```
class UserRepository @Inject constructor(private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>) {


suspend fun saveUserCredentials(credentials: UserCredentials) {
    val usernameKey = stringPreferencesKey("username")
    val passwordKey = stringPreferencesKey("password")

    dataStore.edit { preferences ->
        preferences[usernameKey] = credentials.username
        preferences[passwordKey] = credentials.password
    }
}

suspend fun getUserCredentials(): UserCredentials {
    val usernameKey = stringPreferencesKey("username")
    val passwordKey = stringPreferencesKey("password")
    val data = dataStore.data.first()

    val username = data[usernameKey] ?: ""
    val password = data[passwordKey] ?: ""

    return UserCredentials(username, password)
}
```

}

Una clase Application

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
@HiltAndroidApp

class TareasCampoApp : Application() {
    val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "user_preferences")
}
```

Y ahora estoy haciendo un módulo para obtener una instancia de DataStore pero no logro hacerlo funcionar, no me reconoce el createDataStore, podrían por favor indicarme porque no me reconoce el createDataStore por más que intenté importarlo, o cual podría ser el código correcto para esto? GRACIAS. Les dejo el módulo

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataStoreModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDataStore(context: Context): DataStore<Preferences> {
        return context.createDataStore(name = "user_preferences")

    }
}
```

También les voy a dejar una imagen para que vean que no me está reconociendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mm, leyendo algo del código fuente de la libreria de preferences-datastore, DataStore<T> es una interface, luego, si el datastore es una dependencia, puedes crearte una clase / object en kotlin que implemente los métodos de DataStore<T>, y así, usas DI para inyectar esta fake datastore en la ejecución de la prueba unitaria.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es debido a que se necesita un contexto,  veo que lo estas "inyectando",

```
fun provideDataStore(context: Context): DataStore<Preferences> {
    return context.createDataStore(name = "user_preferences")
}
```

por lo tanto, me parece que el problema es el import, asegura estás usando el import:

```
import android.content.Context
```

ya que si usas una clase diferente no podrás usar el método `createDataStore()`